# Responsive Height on a wordpress slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Having an issue with the height of my slider on my site. No matter what CSS I add or how I change the Jquery it still will not look right on mobile. If I add a height of lets says 300px it looks great in browser but on mobile it creates a huge gap!

http://www.proteadental.com/

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your slider `max-height:auto` and remove `height:300px`